# Creating a rectangle with shadow effect borders

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to create a shadow effect around the edges on a rectangle that I want to add on a JPanel.

```
This is how I will be creating the rectangles but I don't know how to add shades around   
the edges


public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        g.drawRect(340,315, 200, 120);

        g.drawRect(5,315, 200, 120);


    }
```

Comment: How about using drawLine(...) around the 2 edges? Or if you want a thicker shadow use fillRect(...) around the 2 edges. Also the method to override is `paintComponent(...)` not paint() and you invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` (without the "s"). Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: None of the built in [borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) work for you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add a panel with shaded edges or you can look for solutions here

> [JPanel Drop Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368103/jpanel-drop-shadow)